# How to print PDFs automatically

Tags: java, pdf, printing, jms

We have a number of systems that produce PDFs that need to be printed.  These are stored on a central document store.  A message then goes onto a JMS queue that the document needs printing.  A service, written in Java , picks these up and then invokes a native command.  This is to call Adobe Reader with the /t flag.  This causes the document to print without the GUI showing.

However since a power cut this no longer works.  In the interim we are having to manually print hundreds of documents.  We originally tried using Java printing, but the PDFs came out malformed.

What is a better solution to this?

Comment: So, why not duplicate the service locally. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: A "power cut"?  What do you mean?

Comment: We lost power to the building and this machine wasn't on the UPS :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code only works if the printer supports PDF. Otherwise you need to use a native printer or a Java library. There is a blog article on this at http://pdf.jpedal.org/java-pdf-blog/bid/25566/Printing-PDF-files-from-Java

Comment: Thanks. This has got it very close to working with option 1.  The printer does say that it supports "Direct PDF Printing".  It is a HP CM8050.  Just got a couple of issues with fonts now, but no layout issues like before.

Comment: 3 years later this answer was helpful, and since the given link is broken, here is the [new one](http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2010/01/printing-pdf-files-from-java/)

Answer (score 1):

Show us the code. I remember printing PDF with no issues using Java Print API. Below is the code, might need some modification, but should run as it is,

```
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF;

        // find the printing service
        AttributeSet attributeSet = new HashAttributeSet();
        attributeSet.add(new PrinterName("FX", null));
        attributeSet.add(new Copies(1));

        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
                DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF, attributeSet);

        //create document
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(in, flavor, null);

        // create the print job
        PrintService service = services[0];
        DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

        // monitor print job events
        PrintJobWatcher watcher = new PrintJobWatcher(job);

        System.out.println("Printing...");
        job.print(doc, null);

        // wait for the job to be done
        watcher.waitForDone();
        System.out.println("Job Completed!!");
```

Note:

- `Flavor` is not needed in 2 places, 1 place should be enough. You find that out.
- `PrintJobWatcher` is a nested class, to add a `PrintJobListener`.

Comment: This is pretty much what we had.  This works fine for simple layouts but anything more elaborate with differing fonts and layouts that it starts to fail.  That's why we fell back to using Adobe Reader.

Comment: So, why not duplicate the service locally? Is there any problem with that.

Comment: This actually require the underlying (OS specific) printing system to support PDF and in case the OS printing support for PDF is limited, your code will fail. The code will not work at all under Windows and I suppose most Linux print spoolers are built around ghostscript, which has quite a few limitations in the PDF support.

Comment: As @jarnbjo said, INPUT_STREAM_PDF is returning invalid flavor for me on Windows. Whilest using `AUTO_SENSE` renders a blank printout.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ICEpdf](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEpdf/overview.jsf). Here's an example from [documentation page](http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/PDF/Print+Services+Example):

```java
Document pdf = new Document();
pdf.setFile(filePath);

// create a new print helper with a specified paper size and print
// quality
PrintHelper printHelper = new PrintHelper(null, pdf.getPageTree(),
        0f, MediaSizeName.NA_LEGAL, PrintQuality.DRAFT);
// try and print pages 1 - 10, 1 copy, scale to fit paper.
printHelper.setupPrintService(selectedService, 0, 0, 1, true);
// print the document
printHelper.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ever since Java 1.5, Sun developed a pdf renderer library for handling PDF. Now this one is left to Swing Labs. And not sure whether this one would be added into future java APIs.
http://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer/

It is used to view or print pdf files. to print pdf files, you can call this libray. Here is some part of the code.

```
File input = new File(docName);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(input);
FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());

PDFFile curFile=null;
PDFPrintPage pages=null;
curFile = new PDFFile(bb); // Create PDF Print Page
pages = new PDFPrintPage(curFile);
PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

PrintService[] services = pjob.lookupPrintServices();
for(PrintService ps:services){
    String pName = ps.getName();
    if(pName.equalsIgnoreCase("PrinterName")){
        pjob.setPrintService(ps);
        System.out.println(pName);
        break;
    }
}

pjob.setJobName(docName);
Book book = new Book();
PageFormat pformat = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();
book.append(pages, pformat, curFile.getNumPages());
pjob.setPageable(book);

// print
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();


// Print it
pjob.print(aset);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/). Examples:

### a) Printing PDF as `Pageable`

```
PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();

PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("doc.pdf"));
PDFPageable pdfPageable = new PDFPageable(pdDocument);
SimpleDoc doc = new SimpleDoc(pdfPageable, DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE, null);

printJob.print(doc, null);
```

### b) Printing PDF as `Printable`

This option has advantage that you can control page dimensions, margins, etc. by modifying `pageFormat` variable.

```
PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();
PageFormat pageFormat = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();

PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("doc.pdf"));
PDFPrintable pdfPrintable = new PDFPrintable(pdDocument);

Book book = new Book();
book.append(pdfPrintable, pageFormat);
SimpleDoc doc = new SimpleDoc(book, DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE, null);

printJob.print(doc, null);
```