# How do I send an flyingsaucer generated pdf to printer?

Tags: java, pdf, flying-saucer

I've had success creating pdf using flyingsaucer in java. But I'd like instead of saving the pdf in hard disk, send the pdf straight to printer. Or is it job done by another library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flying-saucer doesn't support printing, but you can try **java's printing service** as described [here](http://bfo.com/blog/2012/02/15/using_java_to_print_pdf_documents.html). Maybe [**JPedal**](http://www.idrsolutions.com/java-pdf-library/) is an option, but it's not free ([Example](http://files.idrsolutions.com/samplecode/org/jpedal/examples/printing/SilentPrint.java.html)).

**Additional Links:**

- http://www.coderanch.com/t/410208/java/java/java-printing-printing-pdf
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html
- [How to print PDFs automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191183/how-to-print-pdfs-automatically)
- [Printing PDF to network printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139828/printing-pdf-to-network-printer)
- [how to print a PDF on an unmapped network printer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441063/how-to-print-a-pdf-on-an-unmapped-network-printer-in-java)
- [Print a PDF file using PrinterJob in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293859/print-pdf-using-printerjob-in-java)